# How to find and list hidden files in bash?

Tags: bash, files, hidden-files

How to list only files which begin with a period character?
I want to know how this it possible with `ls`, `grep` and `find`.

Answer (score 3):

To see only files whose name begins with '.' just use '.*' in all commands.

Examples:

```
ls .*
find . -name '.*'
grep xy .*
```